# $\frac{\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]}{x^5+y^3+z^2}$ is UFD

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

I wish to show

> $A=\dfrac{\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]}{x^5+y^3+z^2}$ is UFD

What I have tried so far:

I was thinking of applying Nagata's criterion. Indeed, $-(x^5+y^3)$ cannot be a square in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$. Hence $A$ is a domain. Note that
$$\frac{A}{xA}=\frac{\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]}{(x,x^5+y^3+z^2)} \cong \frac{\mathbb{C}[y,z]}{y^3+z^2}$$
which is a domain as $-y^3$ is not a square in $\mathbb{C}[y]$. Hence $x$ is a prime in $A$. Thus enough to check $A[\frac1x]$ is a UFD.
Now I am stuck here. I cannot simplify the ring $A[\frac1x]$.

Any help/ suggestions to tackle this problem.

Comment: Hint. $A[x^{-1}]=\mathbb C[y',z',x]$ where $y'=y/x^2$ and $z'=z/x^3$.

Comment: Although this question isn't an *exact* duplicate of the linked one, the proof is very similar.

Comment: Please see if I am correct or not: $y', z'$ are algebraic independent. So, $B=\mathbb{C}[y',z']$ is UFD. Now let $S$ be set consisting of $(y'^3+z'^2)^k$, $k\ge 0$. It is multiplicative closed. Thus $S^{-1}B$ is UFD. Note that $-\frac{1}{y'^3+z'^2}$ can be identified with $x$ in $A[x^{-1}]=\mathbb{C}[y,z][x]$. Hence we get that $A[x^{-1}]$ is UFD.

Comment: Of course you are!

Comment: @Sayan so what you are basically saying is that take $y^/ = y/x^2, z^/ = z/x^3,x^/=1/x$ and thus, $A[x^{-1}]= \Bbb C[x^/, y^/, z^/, \frac{1}{x^{/} }] \cong \Bbb C[y^/ , z^/][- \frac{1}{{y^{/}}^3 +{z^{/}}^2}]$ and thus by Nagata we're done, right?